# Fast way to find all dirs with a given glob

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following snippet of shell:

```
find .                          \
     -not \(                    \
         \(                     \
             -path ./vendor -o  \
             -path ./_\* -o     \
             -path ./.\* -o     \
             -path ./docs -o    \
             -path ./examples   \
         \) -prune              \
     \)                         \
     -type f -name \*.go        \
     | sed 's|^./||'            \
     | xargs -n1 dirname        \
     | sort -u                  \
```

It works, but it takes 4-5 seconds to run.  I'm looking for ideas on how to make it faster.  Any directory with a single *.go file qualifies.  Output must be just the directory names, and must be `dir/subdir` not `./dir/subdir`

edit: This dir-tree has thousands of files in many hundreds of directories. I expect to find O(hundreds) of directories that match.

Any clever ideas, O shell wizards?

Comment: Can you describe in words what you're doing?  How many results does your `find` invocation return?

Comment: Subsequent runs of `find` will be faster anyway. Also look at query optimization options for find.

Comment: and give us some idea of the scale of what you are filtering. What is output from `find . -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l | wc -l` ? (or similar). If you searching 1000s of files, 4-5 secs sounds good to me. Good luck.

Comment: edit added.  This dir-tree has thousands of files in many hundreds of directories. I expect to find O(hundreds) of directories that match.

Comment: Given that you have thousands of files in hundreds of directories, and `find` gives you hundreds of directories, a total runtime of 4-5 seconds is not unreasonable.

Comment: ++ for replying AND (now that I think about it) a very good example of a medium complex `find` as well as a good shell pipeline! If you timed each element, the `find` will dwarf any optimizations in the rest of the pipeline. Life is short, get on with it ;-) Good luck.

Comment: I was hoping there would be faster short-circuits or something I didn't know about.  :(

Comment: Try using the `-O` flag which enables query optimization.  `-O3` is the highest level.  Read up about it `man find` and search for `-Olevel`.

Comment: -O had no effect, but I had an idea to cache results and do an initial pass lookng for any directory -newer than the cached result.  This is very fast (50ms) and tells me whether I need to do the heavier find at all.

Comment: How do you tell find to look at the cache? (or how are you doing that!), I'll be happy to vote for that as a solution to your problem. Good luck.

Comment: @TimHockin If you would add a little script that set's up a test environment it would be worth looking at it. Important is that we are working with the same test scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it was significantly faster to cache the results of this find in a file, and then run a pre-find to see if any directories are newer than the cache.

```
find .                      \
 -not \(                    \
     \(                     \
         -path ./vendor -o  \
         -path ./_\* -o     \
         -path ./.\* -o     \
         -path ./docs -o    \
         -path ./examples   \
     \) -prune              \
 \)                         \
 -type d                    \
 -newer ${CACHE}            \
 -print -quit               \
 | wc -l
```

If that returns "1" then I need to run the slow path.  Most of the time I don't, though, so I can use the cache.